# IOError Input/Output Error When Printing to logger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, printing, ioerror, log4r

I have a simple function, that being called from worker and prints lines into logger - using log4r.

I'm sometimes getting this error in my log:

```
Errno::EIO: Input/output error - <STDOUT>
```

Seems that it is unable to write to STDOUT.

When/why could the above error occur?

Googling turned up nothing useful.